# Work done against an internal force

Tags: work

The internal force can be due to electric field or gravitational field. Can "work done against gravity" be negative? Or do we not use the word "against" when this work comes out negative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that gravity is acting downward. Then work done against it will be when a force displaces the object upwards. However you say that work done against gravity is negative which means that the force displaced the object downwards.

Imagine a man freely falling with a jetpack on his back accelerating him downwards. The work done by the jetpack against gravity will be negative.

Answer (score 1):

1) Whenever things fall down, a positive work is done by gravity.

2) Whenever things go up, a positive work is done against gravity.

If someone is trying to prevent things from falling down, but fails to do so, I suppose we can say that a negative work was done against gravity, but, since this scenario falls under (1), it is more accurate to say that a positive work was done by gravity.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes.

Longer answer: It all depends on how you define your coordinates. I assume you mean a situation like the electric force is upward and the gravitational force is downward. If you define the upward direction to be negative and the downward to be positive you will know the sign of the displacement $\vec{d}$. In this situation, if the gravitational force caused an object to move downward then the work $W_g=\vec{F_g} \cdot \vec{d}$ would be positive because the direction of $\vec{F_e}$ and $\vec{d}$ are in the same direction. If you calculated the work done by electric for the same event $W_e=\vec{F_e} \cdot \vec{d}$ would be negative because $\vec{F_e}$ and $\vec{d}$ are in opposite directions. So you would say that the electric force has done **negative work** on the object after the gravitational force has moved it downward. So the electric force working "against" gravity has resulted in a negative work value.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didnt explain myself clearly. Let say theres only gravity which creates the internal force on a body. Can work done by an external force against gravity ever be negative in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the force that is acting................

I go by the definition that energy into the system is positive .That's why work done by external force is positive because it tends to increase the energy of the system by bringing  energy from outside.The opposite of which the system does ie work done by system is negative because it is equivalent on spending energy on something external.It's just my assumption not an absolute fact.There are cases where the work done by the system is positive so it can be defined in both Ways.In short it depends on the force that is acting and whether the work done by system is positive or negative.

When we try to raise an object then work done against gravity is positive and by gravity is negative because the energy of the system has increased so typically energy has to be provided externally.

When objects fall then the energy of the system is decreasing then  we can think in this way that energy is decreasing hence gravity would be doing positive work(here to show energy is decreases)

Just remember that whenever potential energy is increased,negative work is done by conservative forces and vice versa.

Hope this helps